# change direction of networkx graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

```
    def find_connected_components(self, graph):
        visited = []
        connected_components = []
        for node in graph.nodes:

            if node not in visited:
                cc = []  # connected component
                visited, cc = self.dfs_traversal(graph, node, visited, cc)

                connected_components.append(cc)
        return connected_components
    def dfs_traversal(self, graph, start, visited, path):
            
      if start in visited:
        return visited, path
      visited.append(start)
           
      path.append(start)
           
      for node in graph.neighbors(start):
               
         visited, path = self.dfs_traversal(graph, node, visited, path)
      return visited, path
```

Hi , does anyone know how to change the direction of networkx?
For example, the first network, at the moment when I traverse using DFS,
the order : FENWICK ST->STEVEN ST-> NEWCOMBE ST-> DRYSDALE ST.
Yet I would like to achieve
STEVEN ST-> FENWICK ST->NEWCOMBE ST-> DRYSDALE ST.
I assume it has to do with the direction which is why the result isnt in order.
does anyone know how to do this? I would like it to start from the start/ end of the node not from the middle.
also, if the fourth graph, I would like to print the node in this order: FFF->EEE->b->a
FFF->EEE->b->c-d -WWW-ZZZ-VVV-UUU-TTT-SSS-KKK
FFF->EEE->b->c-d -WWW-ZZZ-VVV-UUU-TTT-SSS-RRR-OOO
btw, I use the code above to print each of the connected networkx
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the reverse function for directed graphs:

```
H = G.reverse(copy=True)
```

[NetworkX Documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.reverse.html)